# I have a Collection of Multiple Classes, I need one iterator and that object casted

Tags: java, casting, iterator

I have an ArrayList and i have a collection of those of different objects

Then i have an iterator on it

```
for(Iterator i = results.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

Object row = i.next();
```

The issue is that I have multiple classes using this. For example User.class. How do i make sure I get that object casted

`User u = (User) row?`

Comment: You don't use a raw `ArrayList` nor a raw `Iterator`. You declare your list to contain a particular type, e.g. `ArrayList<User>`. You don't use the same list for multiple types unless there is a compelling reason.

Comment: You **could** but **should not** use the `instanceof` operator

Comment: That is bad design. Your List should hold one type or subclasses of the same type, not arbitrary objects.

Comment: If you have the code, change the design.

Comment: @S.Iqbal Don't try to extend broken code, fix it!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**use instanceof !**

```java
 for(Iterator i = results.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

    Object row = i.next();

    if (row instanceof User) {
       User u = (User) row; // this is safe
       // ...
    }

 }
```

**with multiple types**

```java
 for(Iterator i = results.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

    Object row = i.next();

    if (row instanceof User) {
       User u = (User) row; // this is safe
       // ...
    } else if (row instanceof Stuff) {
       Stuff u = (Stuff) row; // this is safe
       // ...
    }

 }
```

**with multiple types in a generic list**

```java
 Collection<? extends Human> results = ... ;
 for(Human h : results) {

    if (h instanceof User) {
       User u = (User) h; // this is safe
       // ...
    } else if (h instanceof Man) {
       Man m = (Man) h; // this is safe
       // ...
    } else if (row instanceof Woman) {
       Woman w = (Woman) h; // this is safe
       // ...
    }

 }
```

**foreach variant**

```java
for (Object row : results) {
    if (row instanceof User) {
       User u = (User) row; // this is safe
       // ...
    }
}
```

**java 8 variant**

```java
results.stream().filter(row -> row instanceof User).map(row -> (User) row).forEach(user -> {...});
```

HTH!

Comment: That's bad design using raw types. Not recommended in any way.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the OP says he has multiple types in the collection.

Comment: @Highbrainer at least use a wildcard like `Collection<?>`

Comment: @Lino I have no problem with generics, my sample code did not include the definitions ! Note that having a declared ancestor in the list's type does not mean that you must have the exact same behaviour for each actual child instances in your collection. I updated my answer to make is (a little?) more helpful - hopefully.